# Relative Path in ASP.NET Web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have the following tag in my ASP.NET Web.config application:

```
<add name="monitorEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MonitorDB.csdl|res://*/Models.MonitorDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.MonitorDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Documents and Settings\jdoe\Desktop\LcdManager\LcdManager\App_Data\monitor.sqlite&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

that refers to an EntityFramework instance mapping a sqlite db located in the App_Data directory of the application.

How can i make the link relative so that deploying in a production environment is easier?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<add name="monitorEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MonitorDB.csdl|res://*/Models.MonitorDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.MonitorDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;./App_Data/monitor.sqlite&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

or

```
<add name="monitorEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MonitorDB.csdl|res://*/Models.MonitorDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.MonitorDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|/monitor.sqlite&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't you use "|DataDirectory|" in the connection string (instead of C:...\App_Data)? E.g:

```
connectionString="... |DataDirectory|\monitor.sqlite ..."
```

I know this works for SQL Server Express databases that are deployed in the app_data folder of the application. But I don't know if this works for Entity Framework / SQLite.

Comment: Does that work when built on one server and deployed to another?

Comment: As long as your database is in the App_Data folder of the deployed application.

Comment: doh! yes web.config not compiled, duh me :-( This is probably the right way to do it then, not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about this bit

```
C:\Documents and Settings\jdoe\Desktop\LcdManager\LcdManager\App_Data\monitor.sqlite
```

instead, try this

```
../../App_Data/monitor.sqlite
```

(not sure about the number of '../' but you get the idea 
    ../../App_Data/monitor.sqlite